# Map two arrays by index in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table with two columns with comma separated values. I would like to map them by index

```
item_list             item_type
'400,500,600,700'    'st1,st2,st2'
```

**Desired Output**

```
item    type
400     st1
500     st2
600     st2
700     NULL
```

I have tried using the following but it just repeates the value or each item.

```
select distinct a.value::string as a1
       ,b.value::string as a2
from (select '400,,500,600,700'as c1
         ,'st1,st2,st2' as c2
     ) as x,
     lateral flatten(input=>split(c1, ',')) a,
     lateral flatten(input=>split(c2, ',')) b
order by a1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to flatten them separately, and join on their indexes:

```
with 
x as (select '400,500,600,700'as c1,'st1,st2,st2' as c2),
a as (select value::string a1, index from x, lateral flatten(input=>split(x.c1, ','))),
b as (select value::string a2, index from x, lateral flatten(input=>split(x.c2, ',')))
select a1,a2 from a full outer join b on a.index=b.index;
```

Similarly, with SPLIT_TO_TABLE():

```
with 
x as (select '400,500,600,700'as c1,'st1,st2,st2' as c2),
a as (select value::string a1, index from x, lateral split_to_table(x.c1, ',')),
b as (select value::string a2, index from x, lateral split_to_table(x.c2, ','))
select a1,a2 from a full outer join b on a.index=b.index;
```

---

Further clarification by @Andrii Soldatenko -- Thank you:

to explain idea i would recommend to run first this:

```
select * from(select 'st1,st2' as c2) as x2,
                                            lateral flatten(input=>split(c2, ',')) b;
+---------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
| C2      | SEQ | KEY  | PATH | INDEX | VALUE | THIS     |
|---------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+----------|
| st1,st2 |   1 | NULL | [0]  |     0 | "st1" | [        |
|         |     |      |      |       |       |   "st1", |
|         |     |      |      |       |       |   "st2"  |
|         |     |      |      |       |       | ]        |
| st1,st2 |   1 | NULL | [1]  |     1 | "st2" | [        |
|         |     |      |      |       |       |   "st1", |
|         |     |      |      |       |       |   "st2"  |
|         |     |      |      |       |       | ]        |
+---------+-----+------+------+-------+-------+----------+
2 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.357s
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.